# Onbind method in recycle adapter

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am making a simple recycle view. After I extended the recycleview adapter, and implemented the methods my onbind method looks like this:

`public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder, int i)`

Every tutorial I follow there is no 'i' its 'position' there. Please explain why I am not getting position ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn´t matter what the name of the variable is. May it `i`, `position`, `foo` or something else. But its always the position of the item. This is what the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#bindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) says:

> **bindViewHolder(VH holder, int position)** 
>   This method internally calls
>   onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int) to update the
>   RecyclerView.ViewHolder contents with the item at the given position
>   and also sets up some private fields to be used by RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

When you are implementing methods with Android Studio, it creates empty methods. Each parameter of a method has to have a name and Android Studio creates it for you. 
Once you've got

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder, int i)
```

you can rename `imageViewHolder` and `i` as you wish, because eventually android will call your method basing on the method's name and the method's argument types (not names).
A `position` name makes more sense, than just `i`, so the tutorial's author decided to name this int that way.